# Why this viewController property doesn't prevent the object from being deallocated?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, dealloc, retain-cycle

Please consider the following code:

```
class Module {
    let viewController = ExampleViewControler()

    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
}

class ExampleViewControler: UIViewController {}



@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        let mod = Module()
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mod.viewController)
        window?.rootViewController = navController

        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```

The viewController is retained by the navController. Why is the deinit called on the Module instance? Shouldn't it be retained as well since it's property is retained?

Anyway, I would like to keep the object alive as on as it's view controller is alive. How can I achieve that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mod` variable is not retained by anyone. It's an internal variable of the function. As soon as the function exits the `mod` is being deallocated. No one retains it.

Comment: Yes but shouldn't Module have a strong reference to viewController?

Comment: To clarify, an object will retain its properties (unless they are `weak`) but having some other object also retaining the object that the property refers to (in this case, the navigation controller) does not mean that the object itself will be retained. *Something* needs to hold a reference to `mod` to prevent it being released

Comment: @Davide it has a strong refernce _to_ viewController, but no one has a strong reference _to_ `mod`.

Comment: Ok, understood. Marked as accepted. Thank you and thanks to Paulw11 too for the clarification.